# Mean Value Theorem with integral remainder?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K$ be a Lipschitz continuous real function, $x_1, x_2\in [0,1]$ and $x\in (h,1-h)$ for some small $h>0$. An author states that

> If the Mean Value Theorem  with integral remainder is considered, the we find
>   $$K\Big(\frac{x_2-x}{h}\Big)=K\Big(\frac{x_1-x}{h}\Big)+\frac{x_2-x_1}{h}\int_0^1 K'\Big( \frac{x_1-x+\delta(x_2-x_1) }{h}\Big)d\delta.$$

Can anyone explain me how to obtain that?

**My attempt**

For me, this is very straightforward. From Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, 
$$K\Big(\frac{x_2-x}{h}\Big)-K\Big(\frac{x_1-x}{h}\Big)=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} K'\Big( \frac{u-x}{h}\Big)du.$$
Using integration by substitution, $\delta=(u-x_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ we have
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} K'\Big( \frac{u-x}{h}\Big)du=(x_2-x_1)\int_0^1 K'\Big( \frac{x_1-x+\delta(x_2-x_1) }{h}\Big)d\delta$$
We are done.
I have no idea where "MVT with integral remainder" comes in though.

Is it acceptable?

Comment: The word should be *remainder* (what “remains”), not *reminder*.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks

Comment: The name does not seem to be neither important nor a standard one. Your computation seems to be correct and straightforward.